# Save and load state of GUI component

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, persistence

I am new to GUI development, may be this is very easy to do, however, any help will be appreciated.

Considering that I have a GUI with 7-8 tabs, and each tab contains text boxes, check boxes and radio buttons, list-boxes and so on.

The idea is to after filling the tabs, the user can save all the data (state of the components) in a file.

And later on by loading the corresponding file, the user can retrieve all the data.

How can I able to do it without manually save all the data?

**Update:**

Please consider, I have the following GUI application that collect student information:
[Sample application Tab # 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m2aD.png)

As there are several tabs, the user may stop anytime ans save the information in a file, such as: [Saving information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsGmX.png)

The idea is that the user can load the file later and continue his/her task.

I would like to know how I can save the state of all the components in the application and load later on.

Thanks.

Comment: *"How can I able to do it without manually save all the data?"* Hire a programmer to do the manual work for you.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I do not want to mean that. I want to know is there any straight forward to do that.

Comment: No. Creating methodology to iterate all the components of the GUI and serialize them would be long but trivial. Creating methodology to restore the state to the correct components - harder.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up two things here: UI and data.

The **data** that you save to a file should represent the "mental model" that you build your whole application around.

Example: you seem to think of a "Person" as a collection of text fields and checkboxes ... and that is **wrong**: a Person is a distinct class, with a set of fields respectively methods that represent behavior.

And a Person object can *somehow* be displayed within your UI. But what you *persist* are Person objects, not text fields and checkboxes!

In other words: you should **first** understand the object model that your application is dealing with. You learn the different ways to *persist* that data. And based on that, you look into providing a good graphical user experience. And when you are there, your first stop should be [models](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/model.html) - the Swing concept to "map" data to UI elements.